# Python: Simple question about comparing multiple arguments in a function (updated)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to work out how to check the input with multiple strings 
Example, a football quiz, here the answer is 2003-2004

```
guess1 = input('which years did Arsenal go unbeaten?')
   check_guess(guess1, '2003-2004')
```

but what about if I want to say both 2003 or 2004 are correct? I add 'or' in 
but it doesn't work, it will only accept the first string of 2003, how to i make it to accept either string?

```
    guess1 = input('which years did Arsenal go unbeaten?')
    check_guess(guess1, '2003') or check_guess(guess1, '2004')
```

Here's the full script

```
#This is a football quiz
def check_guess(guess, answer):
  global score
  still_guessing = True
  attempt = 0
  while still_guessing and attempt < 3:
      if guess.lower() == answer.lower():
          print('You smarty-pants!, correct answer!')
          score = score + 1
          still_guessing = False
      else:
          if attempt < 2:
              guess = input('You dilly, wrong answer. Try again.')
          attempt = attempt + 1
  if attempt == 3:
      print('This was your last chance, Pal, the correct answer is ' + answer)

score = 0
print('Football quiz!')
guess1 = input('Between which years did Arsenal go unbeaten?')
check_guess(guess1, '2003-2004')
guess2 = input("What is the score of Arsenal's record win against Grimbsy town?")
check_guess(guess2, '9-1')
guess3 = input("Which year marked Arsenal's final game at Highbury?")
check_guess(guess3, '2006')
guess4 = input('Which country won the first ever fifa football world cup in 1930?')
check_guess(guess4, 'Uruguay')
guess5 = input('Who is the top scorer of Arsenal in all time?')
check_guess(guess5, 'Henry')
guess6 = input('How many goals did he score for Arsenal?')
check_guess(guess6, '228')
print('Your score is ' + str(score))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your check_guess function

Answer (score 0):

Define your function like this :)

```py
def check_guess(year):
    if year in ['2003','2004']:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should do what you want:

```
def check_guess(year):
    if ('2003' in year) or ('2004' in year):
        return True
    return False

guess1 = input('which years did Arsenal go unbeaten?')
check_guess(guess1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function do what you want and keep it stateless with the following code

```py
// Takes in a guess in format 'YYYY' E.G `2003`
// Takes in arbitrary amount of years in format `YYYY,YYYY,...`
def check_guess(guess, valid_years):
    list_of_years= valid_years.split(',')

    if guess in list_of_years:
        return True
    return False
```

**Recomended**: You can change the `-` delimiter used to `,` since the `-` delimiter is usually used to specify a range. and if you want to add that behaviour it wouldn't be needed to change usages of this function

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
def check_guess(guess, years):
    return guess in years
```

You can use this function in an if-block to execute code only if the guess is right:

```
if check_guess(guess1, ['2003','2004']):
    # ...
```

Alternatively, you could just use an if statement with an `or` like so:

```py
if (guess1 == '2003') or (guess1 == '2004'):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was looking for.